# Permutations of "MATHEMATICS" containing "MAT"

Tags: combinatorics

I want to determine how many permutations of the word "MATHEMATICS" are possible with the constraint that it must contain the string "MAT".

There are $9$ ways to write the string "MAT" and then $8!$ ways of writing the remaining letters but by simulation this appears to overcount. I believe it is the repetition of the letters in "MAT" that is making this tricky.

Comment: Have you tried treating the string "MAT" as a single letter and permuting the remaining letters?

Comment: Reading both mine and Stefan's answer, I agree with him, so ignore my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Glue the letters "MAT" and consider them as a single letter. Then you have the $9$ letters, namely $MAT, H, E, M, A, T, I, C, S$. There are $9!$ ways to permute these letters, as we have no repetitions of letters.

Now the only possibility of doublecounting is when we have the letters of the other "MAT" triple together. So to take care of this, glue this letters to get $7$ letters, namely $MAT, H, E, MAT, I, C, S$. These can be permuted in $\frac{7!}{2!}$ ways.  Now just subtract these number from the first one, as the second one gives you the number of combinations that appear twice in the upper combinations. Finally the number you're after is:

$$9! - \frac{7!}{2!}$$